# Bash Multiple conditions in while loop

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, boolean-logic, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to get a simple while loop working in bash that uses four conditions, but after trying many different syntax from various forums, I can't find solution.
When i write 'Prod' or 'Dev' or 'Admin', i stay in the loop.

```
while [ -z $vmProfil ] || [ $vmProfil != 'Prod' ] || [ $vmProfil != "Dev" ] || [ $vmProfil != "Admin" ]
do 
    read -p 'Choose vm profil between Prod, Dev or Admin :' vmProfil
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `||` where you should be using `&&`; no matter what value `vmProfil` has, at least on of the `!=` conditions must be true.

```
while [ -z "$vmProfil" ] || { [ "$vmProfil" != 'Prod' ] && [ "$vmProfil" != "Dev" ] && [ "$vmProfil" != "Admin" ]; }
```

You can also check negate the result of checking if any condition is true.

```
while [ -z "$vmProfil" ] || ! { [ "$vmProfil" = 'Prod' ] || [ "$vmProfil" = "Dev" ] || [ "$vmProfil" = "Admin" ]; }
```

I would write this as an infinite loop with an explicit break, though.

```
while :; do
  read -p '...' vmProfil
  case $vmProfil in
    Prod|Dev|Admin) break ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I think you got the logic backwards from the question: "When i write 'Prod' or 'Dev' or 'Admin', i stay in the loop."

Comment: That's what the OP's code does now, which is the opposite of what the prompt implies they want.

Comment: You are correct.  OP's logic in the question is backwards.  The logic he is attempting to do in his code was right. +1

Comment: Also, the unquoted variables are a possible problem, especially in `[ -z $vmProfil ]`-- it'll probably work, but mostly by accident. Double-quote variable references to avoid weird parsing problems.

Comment: Thanks to the quoting `"$vmProfil"` the first check `-z "$vmProfil"` is redundant. I do like the case solution, +1

Comment: thank you very much for your answers.
it works very well